# Radius of Circle Intersecting 5 other circles?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

Five touching circles each have radius 1, and their centers are at the vertices of a regular pentagon. Find the radius of the circle that passes through the points of contact $P,$ $Q,$ $R,$ $S,$ and $T.$

[image]

Enter your answer as a trigonometric value, such as $\cos 20^\circ$.

Comment: This post will attract downvotes if you don't explain what you've tried or where you're stuck.

Comment: A very similar question as that of AIME 1991 problem 11. Refer https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=1991_AIME_Problems/Problem_11

Answer (score 1):

From the given right triangle between circle centers and tangent point of copied (regular pentagonal touching) circles

$$ \dfrac{1}{r}= \tan \phi= \tan \dfrac{360^0}{10}$$

or

$$ r= \cot 36^0 $$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search will yield the formula for a regular polygon's apothem, which is the length you're looking for.

$$r = \frac{s}{2\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)} = \frac{1}{\tan(\frac15\pi)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $O$ be a center of the pentagon. Let $l$ be a distance from $O$ to some vertex. I hope you can compute it. Call it $l$.

Now draw a secant from $O$ through this vertex. Its length is $l+1$; the length of its outer part is $l-1$. Observe that the radius $r$ you are seeking is a length of a tangent. Recall a theorem which connects these three values.

Can you continue?